# Exporte nested list/dictonary in CSV format

Tags: python

Trying to export the following list/dictionary into an CSV file where the "Name" and "Reviews" should be in different columns.

Also trying to add an extra column with a set str(Shore Cliff Hotel).

```
reviews = []

name_pos = response.find('"reviewer_name"')  # find first review
while name_pos >= 0:
    name = ""
    review_blocks = []

    start_pos = response.find('"name"', name_pos)
    end_pos = response.find("</span>", start_pos)

    if end_pos > start_pos >= 0:
        name = response[start_pos + 7: end_pos]

    prev_name_pos = name_pos
    name_pos = response.find('"reviewer_name"', name_pos + 1)  # get next review

    start_pos = response.find('"reviewBody"', prev_name_pos, name_pos)
    while start_pos >= 0:
        end_pos = response.find("</span>", start_pos)
        if end_pos > start_pos >= 0:
            review_blocks.append(response[start_pos + 13: end_pos])
        start_pos = response.find('"reviewBody"', start_pos + 1, name_pos)

    reviews.append((name, "\n".join(review_blocks)))
```

Comment: What are you trying to write out?  `reviews`?  The `csv` module has a `writerows` method that can write a list-of-lists in one go.

Comment: reviews and the names. Also a column that has the hotel name which should be a string ="Shore View Cliff"

Comment: What I meant is, you want to write out the `reviews` list.  Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just collect the rows the way you want them, and let the csv module do the work of quoting those newlines.

```
import csv
...
    ...
    reviews.append((name, "\n".join(review_blocks), "Shore Cliff Hotel"))

fcsv = csv.writer(open('myfile.csv','w'))
fcsv.writerow( ('name','reviews','hotel') )
fcsv.writerows(reviews)
```

Comment: Thank you! I am encountering an issue: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'write'  
```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15312/561915965.py in <module>
      1 import csv
      2 fcsv = csv.writer(open('Desktop/HW3/Shore Cliff Hotel.csv', 'w',newline="",encoding="utf-8"))
----> 3 fcsv.write(('name','reviews','hotel'))
      4 fcsv.writerows(reviews)

AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: Oh, that was dumb of me.  Last minute edit.

Comment: `csv.writer(open('myfile.csv','w'))` won't close file handle until script finishes. That shouldn't be a problem for small scripts though, but theoretically could lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: @OlvinRoght -- In this case, we need the file handle to have at least the same lifetime as the `fcsv` object.  If that object is released, then the file handle will be closed.

Comment: @TimRoberts, the issue is that `fcsv` object won't be released until script finishes, even explicit call of `del writer` is not guarantee that it will be cleaned *(from own experience)*.

Comment: Right.  My point is, that's not a problem here.  While the `fcsv` object lives, we need the file handle to live.  If this were in a function as part of a larger app, the local `fcsv` would evaporate at the end of the function, and the file handle would be closed.